# cmake find_library dependencies between 3rdparty libs

Tags: cmake

My project currently uses libfoo, which uses libbar. Unfortunately there is no pkg-config file.

I am trying to write a `FindFoo.cmake` but I can't find where to specify that libbar is needed to successfully link with libfoo.

Do I just have to to set it manually at the end? Or is there a better way?

```
if(LIBFOO_FOUND)
set(LIBFOO_LIBRARIES ${LIBFOO_LIBRARY} ${LIBBAR_LIBRARIES})
endif()
```

It is important that cmake does not change the order of the -l flags, otherwise there will be unresolved symbols.

Comment: `It is important that cmake does not change the order of the -l flags` - CMake **preserves order** of `target_link_libraries` calls and their arguments. As for linking with `libbar`, it is needed only if *public header* `foo.h` contains calls to functions from `libbar`. If `libfoo` uses `libbar` only internally, additional linking with `libbar` is not needed. (Assuming you have **shared** library `libfoo`, which has been already linked with `libbar` *by itself*.)

Comment: Unfortunately the order is not preservered if some component uses libbar directly, cmake decided to put libbar in front of libfoo. Yes the public header of libfoo contains symbols from libbar

Comment: `Yes the public header of libfoo contains symbols from libbar` - Then `libbar` is a *part of the implementation* of *Foo* API. You have correctly added it to the `LIBFOO_LIBRARIES`. BTW, shouldn't be corresponded operation for the `LIBFOO_INCLUDE_DIR` variable too?

Comment: Yes of course, you are right